# Is this possible to record the audio tracks only if video is also enabled with MediaRecorder?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mime-types, web-mediarecorder

I am working on a scenario where I will ask for the camera and mic permissions before joining the session. so I applied the following constraints in `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`

```
const constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
        width: 1280, height: 720
    }
};
```

Everything works fine till here. But now I want to record the audio tracks only by using [MediaRecorder](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/). Other users can see the other peer's video but in the current session, I just want to record the audio content only for all users.

I tried setting up the MimeType but it still records the video content as well. I think MimeType is just for setting up the mime type for each track.

Do I need to do something on the server side where the blob data is uploaded?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/MediaStream) object on which you'll [add](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream/addTrack) only the audio tracks from your current MediaStream:

```
const recording_stream = new MediaStream();
for (const track of gum_stream.getAudioTracks()) {
  recording_stream.addTrack(track);
}
const recorder = new MediaRecorder(recording_stream);
```